# When button pressed, button.setImage(nil) doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to create Japanese crossword. Use buttons as cells. When trying to insert system image, it works (case mode 1). But when I choose other mode (2), the icon doesn't disappear.

```
let img1 = UIImage(systemName: "multiply"))

@IBAction func cellClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for cell in cellButtons {
        if cell.tag == sender.tag {
            switch typeCell { //when mode changes
                    case 1:
                        cell.setImage(img1, for: .normal)  //work
                    default/*2*/:
                        cell.setImage(nil, for: .normal) //don't work, but running without errors
                    }
        }
    } 
}
```

I was trying to use only sender (without `if cell.tag == sender.tag`; didn't work ), then create IBOutlet collection and run the code above.

Update:
I found and decide to use .isHidden. That works and I also solve my other issue :)
Thanks!

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint at `if cell.tag == sender.tag` ... then step through your code and make sure the code you expect to execute is actually being reached.

Comment: Also, try setting a real second image - does that work?