# button.setImage(nil, for: .normal) not working in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe app in Swift, so I set up 9 buttons with tags from 1 to 9 and call `setImage` to set noughts or crosses. This is working as intended.

The problem comes when trying to reset the board, where I call this piece of code:

```
for i in 1..<10 {
    if let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
        button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

This should remove the image from the button, but it does nothing. The button is set to `Custom` in the storyboard, and the tags are indeed assigned as they should. I also tried getting an outlet for one of the buttons and calling `setImage(nil, for: .normal)` in that one and it didn't work either.

I even created a new project with just a button where I call `setImage`, and it is indeed working for non-nil images but not with `nil` as value.

Has Apple changed the way of removing images? Another question([When button pressed, button.setImage(nil) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883235/when-button-pressed-button-setimagenil-doesnt-work)) seems to have the same problem, but if I work with `isHidden` I can no longer click on the buttons, and it should not be the workaround, looks very hacky to me.

Is this a bug on iOS? Did the implementation change or something?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn’t an answer just a side note. You really should avoid using viewWithTag as much as possible. It’s very much seen as an anti pattern. And there is always a better and safer way to do the thing you are trying to do.

Comment: @Fogmeister Oh, thank you very much! I am following an Udemy course on iOS development, just to get the grasp of the language, the framework, etc. (I have 3 years of experience as Android developer) and the professor used that, I didn't know it was an antipattern!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it may be a bug in iOS 15, but it still works if use the new  [UIButton Configuration API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration) you set its [`configuration`'s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3784627-configuration) [`image`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/3750788-image) instead:

```
button.configuration?.image = nil
```

Be sure to also configure your button's image through its `configuration` property when you want it to have an image on iOS 15, too

Comment: Thank you very much, it definitely worked. Is there any way to report bugs to Apple? Or did they mention this change somewhere? Because I cannot find anything why this would stop working...

Comment: You can submit feedback here https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ though you should check that the error also exists in Xcode 14 and iOS 16

Comment: struggled for hours before finding this answer....fixed my issue with ios15.6